How do I turn a list of corners into a lattice
I'm using a command in Python which analyses a file I have, which contains a 2D rectangular lattice, and returns only a list of corners.
If my lattice consists of N squares, the command returns an array of shape (N,4) where each row has the node indices of the four corners of each square.
For instance, if my lattice had two squares, and the nodes were labelled row-by-row, the array returned from the function would contain the two lines [1,2,4,5] and [2,3,5,6].
Is there an efficient way to transform this list of corner-quadruplets into a full lattice again? Perhaps there's even some built-in function in some package that I don't know about.
For my example, I want the array [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] as a result.
Here is my (highly inefficient, and probably not 100% functional) attempt, which takes the (N,4) array "vertices" and returns the arrays "mesh", containing the nodes in the form I described above, and "facemesh", which contains the lattice 'faces', i.e. the same data as in the original (N,4) array but properly arranged in the lattice formation.
It works by finding one corner, extrapolating the two edges connecting to said corner, and finally solving the rest of the lattice since each lattice 'face' is uniquely defined from only three corners, which makes it easy to find the fourth. The lattice 'face' at the starting corner has three corners, so it's easy to add the fourth, and after that has been done, the same is true about the lattice 'face' to its side.
Mathematically, I think it's an alright solution, but computationally, it's very slow. Doing it with a 30×70 lattice takes around 20 seconds on my computer. Also, I've tried some bigger cases where I'm not sure if it's gotten stuck or if I just didn't give it enough time to finish. If anyone could find a cleverer, or at least faster, solution, I'd be very grateful.
def makemesh(vertices):
    corners = np.unique(vertices)[np.unique(vertices,return_counts=True)[1] == 1]
    edges = np.unique(vertices)[np.unique(vertices,return_counts=True)[1] == 2]
    x,y = len(np.unique(vertices)), (len(corners)+len(edges)+4)/2

    L,W = round((y-(y**2-4*x)**0.5)/2),round((y+(y**2-4*x)**0.5)/2)

    mesh = np.zeros((W,L),dtype=int)

    mesh[0][0] = corners[0]

    where = [corners[0] in j for j in vertices]
    neighbours = [i for i in vertices[where][0] if i in edges]
    for n in neighbours:
        breaker = False
        border = [corners[0],n]
        while not breaker:
            nextwhere = [border[-1] in j and not any([i in j for i in border[:-1]]) for j in vertices]
            nextneighbours = [i for i in vertices[nextwhere][0] if i in edges]
            newpt = [i for i in nextneighbours if i not in border]
            for i in vertices[nextwhere][0]:
                if i in corners:
                    border.append(i)
                    breaker = True
            if not breaker:
                border.append(newpt[0])
        if len(border) == L:
            mesh[0] = border
        else:
            mesh[:,0] = border

    for i in range(W-1):
        for j in range(L-1):
            localvertex = np.array([mesh[i,j],mesh[i,j+1],mesh[i+1,j],mesh[i+1,j+1]])
            where = [mesh[i,j] in n and mesh[i,j+1] in n and mesh[i+1,j] in n for n in vertices]
            mesh[i+1,j+1] = [i for i in vertices[where][0] if i not in localvertex][0]
   
    facemesh = np.zeros(np.shape(mesh),dtype=int)[:-1,:-1]
    for i in range(np.shape(mesh)[0]-1):
        for j in range(np.shape(mesh)[1]-1):
            for k,v in enumerate(vertices):
                if mesh[i,j] in v and mesh[i+1,j] in v and mesh[i,j+1] in v and mesh[i+1,j+1] in v:
                    facemesh[i,j] = k
                    break
   
    return mesh,facemesh

